# Можно ли получить данные json файла без сервера?

Tags: javascript, json, http

Здравствуйте. Интересует можно ли получить локальный json не используя сервер?
например так:

```
var url = 'works.json';
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : 
XDomainRequest;
var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
}
xhr.send();
```

или

```
$.getJSON('works.json', function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

но мне идет такая ошибка:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Horchynskyi/Desktop/start%20new%20web-site/works.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.*

Comment: Аяксом точно нельзя. `<input type='file' />` вам в помощь.

Comment: вы хотите прочитать файл с компьютера клиента?

Comment: ну просто файл будет лежать в папке с сайтом к примеру

Comment: ну вот например когда я работаю с сервером локально чтобы не создавать его и не делать запросы. Просто может есть такой способ как в документ css подключается например)

Comment: Вы открываете локальную html страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы «не может сделать запрос AJAX к локальной файловой системе из внешнего домена в любом браузере - это будет массовым недостаток безопасности, если вы могли бы. Посмотрите Правило ограничения домена. Вы должны открывать HTML страницу так же с помощью протокола file://, а не http://.

Также умолчанию браузер Chrome не позволит вам получить доступ к этому локальному файлу из того же самого домена (FireFox позволит), так как это относится к безопасности, но в любом случае вы хотите получить к нему доступ, закройте все экземпляры chrome, откройте командную строку, измените каталог, где присутствует ваш chrome.exe и выполните команду ниже.

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Также можно создать ярлык с этими параметрами.